# Add class based on dynamical url parameter (click and load)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php script that allows me to dynamically load content on my page based on the url paramter. Also, I have .htaccess set up so the query string prefix is hidden, meaning they look like example.com/games/demons-souls/[?page=]mods.

[?page=] is hidden via .htaccess. So far, so good.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_GET["page"])

    && preg_match("/^[a-z]+$/i", $_GET["page"]) == 1

    && file_exists($pageFile = __DIR__ . "/subpages/" . $_GET["page"] . ".php")) {

    include $pageFile;

}

else {

    include __DIR__ . "/subpages/game.php";

}

?>
```

Now I wanted to show which page is active in a tabpanel, where the active tab is let’s say black. So I’d need to activate the class tab.current. And to do this I need to somehow make my code recognize which url paramter is loaded and dynamically add the .current class to the appropriate tab. I hope I could explain it well enough.

I haven’t got the slightest idea how to accomplish this.

Please help.

**Edit 1:** Here’s an image of what I’d like to achieve:

[image]

**Edit 2:** As requested here’s the HTML code:

```
<nav id="tabs">
    <a class="tab" href="game">Spiel</a>
    <a class="tab" href="releases">Releases</a>
    <a class="tab" href="merchandise">Merchandise</a>
    <a class="tab" href="guides">Guides</a>
    <a class="tab" href="emulation">Emulation</a>
    <a class="tab" href="mods">Mods</a>
    <a class="tab" href="savegame">Savegame</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where do you want to add the class? It should be as simple as checking the value of `$_GET["page"]`.

Comment: I’ve added an image to show where I want the class to be added.

Comment: So basically I want to add the class _current_ to the a-tag which has the same _href_ attribute as the current url parameter.

Comment: That sounds right. If you edit your question to show us the relevant HTML that needs to be changed we might be able to help you with that.

Comment: @kmoser I’ve added the HTML code. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can try the following code:

This is code should run at the top, before your nav links.

```
$url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); //this will give you something like: 'localhost/games/demons-souls/savegame'
$urlParts = explode('/',$url); //then separate string into an array by the forwardslash
$current = $urlParts[count($urlParts)-1]; //this line gets you the current page... in this case will be 'savegame'
```

The next step should be applied to your nav links:

```
<nav id="tabs">
    <a class="tab <?= $current == 'game' ? 'current' : ''; ?>" href="game">Spiel</a>
    <a class="tab <?= $current == 'releases' ? 'current' : ''; ?>" href="releases">Releases</a>
    <a class="tab <?= $current == 'merchandise' ? 'current' : ''; ?>" href="merchandise">Merchandise</a>
    <a class="tab <?= $current == 'guides' ? 'current' : ''; ?>" href="guides">Guides</a>
    <a class="tab <?= $current == 'emulation' ? 'current' : ''; ?>" href="emulation">Emulation</a>
    <a class="tab <?= $current == 'mods' ? 'current' : ''; ?>" href="mods">Mods</a>
    <a class="tab <?= $current == 'savegame' ? 'current' : ''; ?>" href="savegame">Savegame</a>
</nav>
```

Here's what happens in the past code. I used ternary operator to check the name of the `$url` variable and if it match the `href` value a `.current` class will be added.

Or try use the JS hack.

After getting your `$current` in PHP have an HTML input like this:

```
<input id="url_value" type="hidden" value="<?= $current; ?>"/>
```

The input above will have the value of `$current` and therefore this value can be used in JS to match the `href` value and give that `anchor tag` a class of `.current` like this:

```
//the following code will be a JS code
var urlValue = document.getElementById('url_value').value; //here we get the `$current` value from our hidden input box above.
document.querySelector('a[href="'+urlValue+'"]').classList.add('current') //this gets the `<a></a>` tag that has the value of `$current`
```

In my opinion this JS method is more of a hack but it totally works and it removes all those PHP lines in every link in your nav.

Give it a try and let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. It works now! :) However, in the nav part I had to replace `$url` with `$current` because otherwise it wouldn’t check for the last string alone but for almost the whole URL (e.g. /games/demons-souls/savegame). And for the last two links you used `active` as class instead of `current`. That needed to be changed, too.

Comment: I guess there is no way to solve this using some dynamic apporach where you don’t have to apply php code to every single link?

Comment: My bad... I've made the changes on my side too. I'm glad to be of help.

Comment: Actually there is one flawed way of doing it using JS and PHP without having to add PHP to every link.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this method?

Comment: I've added an update in my code. Try that one out and compare the 2.

Comment: I realized that I have a problem, when there’s no url paramter displayed. My php code loads a default page – in this case game.php – if the url just says /games/demons-souls/. I would need some code to handle this exception: If there is no url parameter displayed give the first link in the list the class `current`.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about a scenario like this one. Here's one of the solutions you can have. if no parameter is provided, $urlParts will have 3 array elements ['localhost','games','demons-souls'] but if there's a parameter it will have 4 ['localhost','games','demons-souls','savegame'] and this means you know the array count beforehand and therefore you can have an if-statement when assigning a value to $current, like this: if(count($urlParts) == 4){$current = $urlParts[count($urlParts)-1]}else{$current = 'game'}

Comment: I guess you could do that but it would be very static then. If I’d like to use the same script for a page that’s on another level of the folder structure it wouldn’t work. Maybe some JS script could solve this issue. Or you could somehow add the condition `if (empty($_GET["page"])` to the first link.

Comment: All right, I tried it myself and managed to get it working with the following code: `<?php if (empty($_GET['page'])) { echo 'current'; } elseif (($_GET['page'] == 'game') ) { echo 'current'; } ?>`. What do you think? I bet you can shorten it with ternary operators but I don’t know how to use them yet.

Comment: Better version: `<?= $current == null || $current == 'game' ? 'current' : ''; ?>`

Comment: This is awesome. That ternary operator has to work. If not you can also use the `if(!empty($_GET["page"]))` first, if it is not empty you give the current class to the `$current` value found, else you give it to the `game` nav item.

Answer (score 1):

@Relcode's code for generating the links can be shortened and simplified by putting link data in an array and iterating through it:

```
<nav id="tabs">
<?php
    foreach (
        [
            'game' => 'Spiel',
            'releases' => 'Releases',
            'merchandise' => 'Merchandise',
            'guides' => 'Guides',
            'emulation' => 'Emulation',
            'mods' => 'Mods',
            'savegame' => 'Savegame',
        ] as $key => $description
    ) {
?>
    <a class="tab<?php if ($current == $key ) { ?> current<?php } ?>" href="<?= $key ?>"><?= $description ?></a>
<?php
    }
?>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, I’m always thankful for shorter code!